# Use Ajax call to pass array into Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

I am using a datepicker and I want to query a MySQL database when it is clicked to make certain dates unavailable. How to I pass this array into my JavaScript code where it says "AJAX CALL CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE"?

Here is my code for the Javascript date picker

```
$(function() {

  $('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      },
      isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      var dateRanges = [
AJAX CALL CODE NEEDS TO GO HERE
            ];
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
            }, false);
        }
  });

  $('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      document.getElementById("start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      document.getElementById("end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');

  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
```

Here is the code that needs to be inserted into that code in the PHP file for the ajax call:

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$sql="SELECT start_date, end_date FROM date_ranges ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo  "{ 'start': moment('" . $row['start_date'] . "'), 'end': moment('" . $row['end_date'] . "') },";
mysqli_close($conn);
} 
?>
```

edit: new code with the help of Emiel Zuurbier

```
$(function() {

var dateRanges = null;

$.ajax({
    url: 'getdaterangepicker.php', 
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {  
        if (response) {            
            dateRanges = $.parseJSON(response); 
        }
    }
});

  $('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      },
      isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
            }, false);
        }
  });

  $('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      document.getElementById("start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      document.getElementById("end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');

  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
```

Returns error "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dateRanges.reduce')"

Comment: So you need to get the `start` and `end` dates first, and with those values set the `dateRanges`?

Comment: I need to insert the array fetched by the PHP document into the part that says "AJAX CALL GOES HERE"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **jQuery** we'll use the [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function of jQuery.

In your PHP file change the contents of the while loop to the code below. It will create an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to store the `start` and `end` value in, without `moment` because that is JavaScript, and send the array as [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Because it is an associative array it will be turned into an object which we can use in JavaScript.

```
// Create empty array.
$date_ranges = array();

// Add every row to array;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // Create an associative array to store the values in.
    // This will later be a JavaScript Object.
    array_push($date_ranges, array(
        'start'   => $row['start_date'],
        'end'     => $row['end_date']
    ));

    mysqli_close($conn);

} 

// Send the $date_ranges as JSON.
$json = json_encode($date_ranges); // '[{"start": "2019-08-18", "end": "2019-08-19"}]'
echo $json;
```

In the JavaScript prepare for storing the `dateRanges`. Create a variable before your AJAX call which will hold the result.

Now you can make your AJAX request. This has to be sent to the PHP file in which you defined your logic for getting the result. We want to **get** something from the server, so use the `GET` method. Instruct the AJAX request to expect JSON and handle it accordingly. Set the `dataType` to `'json'`.

When the request is send do something with your response. This can be done by setting the `success` property to a function. This function will receive the response and opens it up for us to use. Decode the response from JSON to JavaScript and voila, you have your result.

**Edit:** Put the AJAX call inside a wrapper function. This way you can use this function multiple times when you deem necessary. Also it creates a way to fire a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) from which we can access our data.

```
// AJAX request wrapper function.
// Call this function to get the dates from the server.
function getDateRanges(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/yourphpfile.php',       // Change this to the uri of your file
        method: 'GET',                 // Use the GET method
        dataType: 'json',              // Expect a JSON response
        success: function(response) {  // What will happen when the request succeeds
            if (response) {            // Check if there is a response
                callback(response);    // Pass the response into the callback
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

So now you can call the server any time you like.

You need your dates before you call the `daterangepicker` function. Before the edit the code would call the AJAX function, but before any value was returned, because it can take a second, the `daterangepicker` was already called and used the `null` value before it had any time to update that `null` value.

This is because of the **A** in **AJAX**, which stands for **Asynchronous**. That means that when the `$.ajax` function is fired it does not wait for it to complete, but goes on executing the rest of the script. Whenever the `$.ajax` function gives a response the `success` function is triggered. But we weren't waiting for it to finish. So we'll adjust that.

Put the code where you set the `datepicker` into the callback of the now created `getDateRanges` function. This causes the `daterangepicker` to wait until the AJAX call is finished and has a value.

See code below:

```
// Get the dates from the server.
// Fire the callback function when the AJAX call has returned a value.
// And use it as the dates variable.
getDateRanges(function(dates) {

    $('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            // Here use your dates that you've got from the server.
            var dateRanges = dates;
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end));
            }, false);
        }
    });

    $('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        document.getElementById("start_date").value = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        document.getElementById("end_date").value = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    });

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });

});
```

More on how to use the ajax function of jQuery, check out [these docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Now the `start` and `end` values are still strings. I did see you were using `moment` in your PHP, but since we removed that from the PHP you'll have to call them in your JS.
You could do that in your reduce function:

```
return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end));
```

I hope this is of any help!

Comment: This is an amazingly detailed response and so incredibly helpful. I am a little confused about the last part though. I followed everything up until how to insert everything into the isInvalidDate function (the reduced function) Every time I try to integrate it I get an error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: Sorry, you put dataRanges instead of dateRanges, threw me off. But when I try to make it work I am still having trouble... please advise.

Comment: When I put console.log(JSON.stringify(dateRanges)); it comes up as null still.

Comment: Could you insert `console.log(response)` at the start of the `success` function to see what the `response` value is?  It might not have to be parsed.

Comment: Yeah, if I do that nothing happens. I don't think it's running. I will update my thread to show my new code

Comment: Well, if it means it doesn't go right, It goes wrong. I've added an error handler for the `$.ajax` function. This will output an error in your console if an error occurs. Try it out. Also, be sure to update your PHP with my example above as your example does not send valid JSON.

Comment: Here is the output I get when I try that: [Log] parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string (index2.php, line 119)
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dateRanges.reduce') and the PHP is updated and correct, it outputs {"start":"2019-08-20","end":"2019-08-25"}{"start":"2019-09-05","end":"2019-09-07"} which I believe is correct for JSON.

Comment: `{"start":"2019-08-20","end":"2019-08-25"}` is definitely what we want. So the problem is, I think, the `$.parseJSON` function which tries to parse JSON when the response is already a JavaScript object. I've updated my code and removed the JSON parser.

Comment: Nope, I get [Log] parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string (index2.php, line 118)
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dateRanges.reduce'). I think the Ajax request isn't running because of how the datepicker is opening... but I am not experienced enough in javascript to be sure.

Comment: What is at this line: `index2.php, line 118`? Also you are able to check if an AJAX request is made in your devtools. In Chrome open up your console, click the cog icon on the right and check the `Log XMLHTTPRequests` checkbox. Now reload the page and see if the console logs a request.

Comment: This is the chrome output: parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 41
2index2.php:131 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null line 118 was console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);

Comment: It's hard for me to figure what is going wrong since I can't run your code. So if you're able to present a live example, or a Codepen / JSFiddle I might be able to figure it out. But from the looks of it, it still seems that the JSON is still being parsed somewhere. Did you remove the  `$.parseJSON` function?

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2yhfprzq/ - thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Okay, I've made a big adjustment because I realized I had overlooked an important aspect of the AJAX call. Read from the **Edit** paragraph.

Comment: I just tried the updated code, however I am getting this error: parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 41 - it leads me to suspect that something is not passing from the PHP document to JSON decoder properly?

Comment: If I switch json to html, it doesn't throw an error, but the dates aren't greyed out. When I put an console.log(dates); right above             return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) { it returns the PHP output correctly.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the `$.parseJSON` function which tries to parse the JSON. But the JSON was already parsed by the `$.ajax` function because `dataType` was set to `'json'`. I tried to tell you two times earlier that the `$.parseJSON` should be removed. But changing the `dataType` to `'html'` works as well :). So, is it working?

Comment: So now the issue I am having is real weird. Everything seems like it is being passed 100% and should be working but the date picker text isn't greyed out as it should be.  Any ideas?

Comment: When I replace [dates] with the actual code that it shroud be receiving it works perfectly, when I put console.log(dates); after it, that gives the correct read out (but two times).

Comment: Have you included this line in your `reduce` function? `return bool || (date >= moment(range.start) && date <= moment(range.end));` **Note the moment() function**

Comment: Check if your PHP file has more than one `echo` in there. You might be outputting more than once. Otherwise, your database may contain more than one `start` and `end` date.

Comment: Yes, that is added in.

Comment: Only one echo in there, and I plan on adding a lot of rows into my database so many start and end dates should be able to be added.

Comment: I've updated my PHP to support multiple rows to be added. **Note:** This will output the JSON as an `array` with objects in them instead of a single object. 
Tony, my friend. I've helped you this far. If there are any more problems with your code I'd suggest you to look for documentation and/or other SO threads. Happy to help you out and good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you, Emiel, you've definitely been so helpful. I wouldn't have gotten this far without you. I will definitely update this thread when I get it figured out. I am thinking it is an issue with date picker.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198155/discussion-on-answer-by-emiel-zuurbier-use-ajax-call-to-pass-array-into-javascri).